# change textbox cursor position on right click event in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

My app in Vb.net resembles a copy paste operation through the use of a right click context menu with options to cut, copy and paste. After copying the text, I want the text to be placed at the position in textbox where the right click had occurred. The copy paste operation is similar to the windows app notepad++. Textbox is not multiline.
I already used the following code based on a post I referred.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.MouseClick

    If (e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right) Then

        If (TextBox1.SelectionLength = 0) Then

            TextBox1.Focus()
            TextBox1.HideSelection = True
            TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(e.Location)

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```